# How can you find the nth digit in a fractal number

Tags: string, math, numbers, sequence

The sequence look like this 112123123412345...
If the input is 55,it should return 1,not 10. And if the input is 56,it should return 0,not 1. You got the idea.

Comment: Nope, did not get the idea of your question. What are you asking? To get code debugged you are not showing? To get your work done free of charge, expecting code for a working program to that "idea"? Sorry, but you need to demonstrate own effort, show all needed information and ask a specific question. Otherwise the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected from your code, what you got, and any error messages.

Answer (score -1):

So we have a sequence composed of the composition of

```
1             1 digit      1 digit total
12            2 digits     3 digits total 
123           3 digits     3*(3+1)/2 = 6 digits total 
1234          4 digits     4*(4+1)/2 = 10 digits total
...
123..89       9 digits     9*(9+1)/2 = 45 digits total
123..8910     11 digits    10*(10+1)/2 + 1 = 56
123..891011   13 digits    11*(10+1)/2 + 3 = 69
123..89101112 15 digits    12*(12+1)/2 + 3*(3+1)/2 = 84 digits
```

This is [OEIS Sequence A165145](https://oeis.org/A165145) and also see the related sequence [OEIS A058183](https://oeis.org/A058183).

A formula for the total number of digits is

```
f(n) = n*(n+1)/2  + {(n-9)*(n-8)/2 : if n>=10} + {(n-99)*(n-98)/2 : if n>=100) + ...
```

Some key points f(9) = 45, f(99) = 99*100/2 + 90*91/2 = 9045, f(999) = 1,395,495.

An outline algorithm for finding the k-th digit would be

1. Find which part of the sequence you are in n<=9, 10 <= n <= 99, 100 <= n <= 999 by comparing k with the boundary values 45, 9045, 1395495.
2. Recover the value of n
3. Find the actual digit which will be k-f(n) along sequence for the n-th number.

If we take 10 <= n <= 99 the formula for the number of digits is

```
n*(n+1)/2 + (n-9)*(n-8)/2 
  =  1/2( n^2 + n + n^2 - 17 n + 72)
  =  n^2 - 8 n + 36
```

So given  45 < k <= 9045 we solve  k = n^2 - 8 n + 36, using the quadratic formula

```
 n = ceil( ( 8 + sqrt(64 - 4 (36 - k)))/2)
```

We need a different quadratic formula for k outside the range.

For example take k = 100, using the formula gives n=13. There are f(12)=84 digits for all the numbers upto 12, so the first digit of the 13th string is at position 85. So we are looking for the 16th digit. We can use the formula

```
digit(l) :=  l <= 9 ? l : (l%2==0 ? floor((l+10)/20) : ((l-11)/2)%10 )
```

to find the actual digit, which is 1.